# Do I have to initialize the database for simple membership or not? MVC contradictiving itself?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Ok, so I setup SimpleMembership, and I was under the impression that I had to run `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)` only once in order to have it set up the database. Later, when I attempt to look up a user id, I get an error telling me that I need to initialize the database before I ever call WebSecurity. Ok... so I put the initialization call back into _ViewStart.cshtml as it suggested. Now I run again and I get the error `The "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method can be called only once.` So I'm damned if I do damned if I don't.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)` in the DatabaseInit method of the DatabaseConfig `App_Start\DatabaseConfig.cs` class like below:

```
    public static void DatabaseInit(string ConnectionName = "DefaultConnection", string userTable = "UserProfile", string userIdColumn = "UserId", string userNameColumn = "UserName", bool autoCreateTable = true)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(ConnectionName, userTable, userIdColumn, userNameColumn, autoCreateTables: autoCreateTable);
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't remember why I thought it was telling me to put it into _ViewStart. I moved it to a file in App_Start and don't seem to have anymore problems.

Comment: Yeah, well you any of those files (as long as they are being initialized in the `Application_Start` of the `Global.asax` file) will work. I just created a `DatabaseConfig` class to keep things organized a bit. But glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's actually quite simple.  You are using some code that requires simple membership PRIOR to where you are normally doing your initialization.  So, you get the error message and you add a call to do the initialization, so now your new code works.. but then it gets to the old code which.. initializes the database again and it throws the error.

The problem is basically that you are trying to access the data too early in the pipeline.  Initialization must occur once each time the App Domain is created (ie, when the app is first started, or after the app is restarted from being shut down by IIS for inactivity).

This is why you should wrap it in a call to WebSecurity.Initialized